# How would I copy all files and folders except for hidden ones?

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

On my drive `S:\` I have a folder X which has multiple files and subfilders, each of which in turn contains its own files and subfolders and so on. Each folder(at any level) contains a hidden folder named the same way, say HID, with several files in it.

I have the same structure in another drive `D:\` - same folder X with the same structure, but with slighly different contents in the files.

Basically I need to copy-and-replace the contents of X from `S:\` into `D:\`, but not touch the hidden folders hamed HID (basically, they are unique in two independent ways - by the fact that they are named HID and by the fact that they are hidden).

I'm lazy to do this manually and don't feel like writing a C++ application to do this either. Is there any easy way to do this using a small bat file or a direct shell command with smart arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in [xcopy](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true) command. As it says, "By default, xcopy does not copy hidden or system files.". It also has an *exclude* option, which seems to be used for ignoring specially named files.

Comment: Can I use it to exclude specially named FOLDERS rather than files?

Comment: If you can't, robocopy can with /XD folders_to_ignore

Comment: @AlexK. It appears you don't specify files to exclude directly. Instead, you specify a filename which *contains* strings which, when found within the full pathname of a file, will make it to be ignored. So I can specify a filename which contains \HID\ and it will ignore the folders.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: lose the `echo` and `pause` if it's echoing the right commands.

```
@echo off
cd /d "s:\folder x"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b /s ^|find /v "\HID\" ') do (
echo copy /y "%%a" "d:%%~pnxa"
pause
)
```